# How do I calculate n modulo 3 in LaTeX?

Tags: calculations

I don't want to display the modulo symbol, I want to programmatically calculate n modulo 3 and display the result.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can also use `\intcalcMod` from the [intcalc](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/intcalc) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{intcalc}

\newcounter{mycount}
\newcommand\Nmodiii[1]{%
\setcounter{mycount}{0}\whiledo{\value{mycount}<#1}
  {$\themycount\pmod 3=\intcalcMod{\value{mycount}}{3}$\\\stepcounter{mycount}}
}
\begin{document}

\noindent A little example: $8\pmod 3=\intcalcMod{8}{3}$

\noindent And a little loop:\\
\Nmodiii{20}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The code that appears in the link posted in a comment, there are some spurious blank spaces producing an undesired indentation of the first line; here's a corrected version:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{forloop}
\usepackage{fmtcount}
\usepackage{intcalc}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\newcounter{i}
\noindent\forloop{i}{1}{\value{i} < 101}{%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\intcalcMod{\value{i}}{15}}{0}}{
        FizzBuzz
    }{%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\intcalcMod{\value{i}}{3}}{0}}{
            Fizz
        }{%
            \ifthenelse{\equal{\intcalcMod{\value{i}}{5}}{0}}{
                Buzz
            }{%
                \thei
            }
        }
    }\\
}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   v
l.32 }`

Comment: Thanks, that helps. I'm writing FizzBuzz for LaTeX, so I need to use the mod result in further calculations, not just display it.

Comment: @mcandre: nothing prevents you from using the result in your calculations!

Comment: Hmm. When I do this, I get `! Missing number, treated as zero.` https://github.com/mcandre/mcandre/blob/master/latex/fizzy.tex

Comment: You are using "value" in your code and you should use `\value` (with a backslash). Also, you could have included that code in an edit to your original question.

Comment: Got it. One more thing: I say `\noindent`, but the first line is still indented. Do you know why?

Comment: @mcandre: yes, you have many spurious blank spaces in you code that should be eliminated by using the `%` character in the appropriate places; however the space in comments doesn't allow me to show you the proper formatting here; in fact, you can delete the `\noindent` safely, once you have eliminated those spurious spaces. You can always start a new question asking how to suppress those spurious spaces.

Comment: (Continuation) The `\noindent` can then go outside the loop.

Comment: Can you fork my code then? I took out as much space as I could without abutting the LaTeX commands, but the first line is still indented.

Comment: @mcandre: I've added the code at the end of my updated answer.

Comment: On my system, even with the `%`s, the first line still has extra spaces before it. Thank you for your patience; I hope we can resolve this annoying little issue.

Comment: @mcandre: are you talking about the *exact* same code I posted at the end of my answer? If so, then maybe we could discuss this in a chat session, if you want to.

Comment: Finally got it working with no extra spaces. For some reason, `\decimal{i}` prepends spaces while `\thei` does not.

Answer (score 44):

There are several nice answers using different packages.  I'd like to note that TeX uses integer arithmetics, so it is easy to program the standard formula a-(a/b)*b, where / means integer division.

#### Plain TeX solution:

```
\newcount\tmpcnta
\def\modulo#1#2{\tmpcnta=#1
        \divide\tmpcnta by #2
        \multiply\tmpcnta by #2
        \multiply\tmpcnta by -1
        \advance\tmpcnta by #1\relax
        \the\tmpcnta}
\modulo{17}{3}
\modulo{19}{3}
\bye
```

#### LaTeX solution:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\makeatletter
\newcommand\modulo[2]{\@tempcnta=#1
        \divide\@tempcnta by #2
        \multiply\@tempcnta by #2
        \multiply\@tempcnta by -1
        \advance\@tempcnta by #1\relax
        \the\@tempcnta}
\makeatother
\begin{document} 
\modulo{17}{3}
\modulo{19}{3}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I used a similar solution in a calendar.

Comment: Why can't you write `\divide#1 by #2` or `\divide\number\numexpr#1\relax by #2`?

Comment: @A.Ellett `\divide` mutates (changes) the thing being divided (as do `\multiply` and `\advance`), and so we want to change our own counter `\tmpcnta` rather than `#1`.

Answer (score 24):

The "expandable" version, using e-TeX's `\numexpr`:

```
\def\truncdiv#1#2{((#1-(#2-1)/2)/#2)}
\def\moduloop#1#2{(#1-\truncdiv{#1}{#2}*#2)}
\def\modulo#1#2{\number\numexpr\moduloop{#1}{#2}\relax}
```

`\truncdiv` and `\moduloop` can be plugged into other expressions. It's necessary to do like this because `\numexpr` performs *rounded* integer division.

Comment: the same idea was used in the `calendarweek` TeX package.

Comment: Hmm, from `\truncdiv{0}{64}` I get -1 and so `\modulo{0}{64}` gives 64.

Comment: I'm using the following for now, which works for positive `#2`: `\def\moduloop#1#2{\ifnum \numexpr(#1 - (#1/#2)*(#2))\relax < 0 (#1 - (#1/#2)*(#2) + #2) \else (#1 - (#1/#2)*(#2)) \fi}` and `\def\truncdiv#1#2{((#1 - \moduloop{#1}{#2})/(#2))}`

Answer (score 22):

The [`fp` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/fp) is small and provides the functionality to do quite complex arithmetic. In the minimal example below the macro `\modulo{<a>}{<b>}` stores the result of `<a> mod <b>` in the macro `\result`, which is then directly printed:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}% http://ctan.org/pkg/fp
\newcommand{\modulo}[2]{%
  \FPeval{\result}{trunc(#1-(#2*trunc(#1/#2,0)),0)}\result%
}
\begin{document}
Some modular arithmetic:
\begin{itemize}
  \item $512 \pmod{7}=\modulo{512}{7}$
  \item $6 \pmod{4}=\modulo{6}{4}$
  \item $15 \pmod{4}=\modulo{15}{4}$
  \item $1234567 \pmod{3}=\modulo{1234567}{3}$
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Since the result is stored in `\result`, it can be used later in the text as well, until another execution of `\modulo` will overwrite `\result`.

Similar functionality in terms of mathematical functions is provided with [`pgf`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf) as well.

Comment: `! Undefined control sequence.
\FP@@upn ...on \string "#2\string "}\edef \FP@tmp 
                                                  {[#2]}\expandafter \FP@upn...
l.38 }`

Comment: Do you receive this error when compiling my MWE?

Comment: Yes. Specs: TeXworks on Mac OS X 10.7.2.

Comment: What distribution of TeX do you have installed? I have TeX Live 2011 with `fp` verion `1995/04/02`.

Comment: @Werner: Works fine for me (MikTeX 2.9, same `fp` version as you).

Comment: For completeness, would you mind adding how to do this with pgf?

Comment: I like that a LaTeX solution to doing modular arithmetic is to load a package designed to do floating point calculations. WHAT!?

Answer (score 17):

LaTeX3 (the `expl3` package) also has a facility for computing modulus (moduli?), namely `\int_mod:nn`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\newcommand{\mymod}[2]{\int_mod:nn{#1}{#2}}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
  The residue of $45$ modulo $19$ is $\mymod{45}{19}$.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 15):

Another solution is to use pgfmath

```
\documentclass{article} 
\input{pgfutil-common.tex}
\usepackage{pgfkeys,pgfmath}
\begin{document}

\pgfmathparse{mod(20,6)} \pgfmathresult %displays 2.0
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\myint}{ \pgfmathresult}  

\myint %displays 2 
\end{document}
```

Comment: It seems that only the package `pgfmath` is necessary. `\input{pgfutil-common.tex}` and `\usepackage{pgfkeys}` could be removed.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the [`calculator`](http://ctan.org/pkg/calculator) package then, type this code:

```
\MODULO{14}{3}{\sol}

$14\pmod{3}=\sol$
```

Comment: Nice, a new package! But you might want to make it clearer that you are the package author...

Comment: How nice! `:)` Feel free to add your package to [our list](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1181). And by the way, welcome to TeX.sx! `:)`

Answer (score 3):

You may use `calc` package as long as the absolute values of the numbers are not exceeding `2^31-1=2147483647`. Otherwise you may use [`bigintcalc`](https://ctan.org/pkg/bigintcalc) package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{calc}
\newcounter{modulo}
\newcommand\modulo[2]{%
  \setcounter{modulo}{#1-(#1/#2)*#2}%
  \arabic{modulo}%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
131 \equiv \modulo{131}{3} &\pmod{3} \\
131 \equiv \modulo{131}{5} &\pmod{5} \\
131 \equiv \modulo{131}{7} &\pmod{7} \\
131 \equiv \modulo{131}{8} &\pmod{8} \\
-97 \equiv \modulo{-97}{3} &\pmod{3} \\
-97 \equiv \modulo{-97}{5} &\pmod{5} \\
-97 \equiv \modulo{-97}{7} &\pmod{7} \\
-97 \equiv \modulo{-97}{8} &\pmod{8} \\
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image: result of \modulo commands]