# I see unexpected characters after working with \newcount

Tags: counters

My code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrartcl}
\begin{document}

\newcount\tmpc
\def\modul#1#2{\tmpc=#1 \divide\tmpc by #2 \multiply \tmpc by #2 \multiply \tmpc by -1 \advance \tmpc by #1\relax \the\tmpc}
\def\addpages{%
\newcount\tmpb%
\tmpb=\modul{\thepage}{4}%
\multiply\tmpb by -1%
\advance\tmpb by 4%
\loop\ifnum\tmpb>0\advance\tmpb by-1 \vspace*{-5cm}\strut\newpage\repeat%
}
hello
\section[123\hbox to \textwidth{} {\rm\small 456}]{test}
\tableofcontents
\addpages
buggy
\addpages
test
\end{document}
```

I see "=1 1" on first page. Why?

Comment: (1) Welcome, (2) what exactly are you trying to do? BTW: it is not a good idea to allocate a count inside a macro

Comment: @daleif, I want to skip some pages. Move to next page with num % 4 == 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The explanation is simple. Let's examine the call

```
\tmpb=\modul{\thepage}{4}
```

After `=`, TeX performs expansion in order to find a `<number>`, so it replaces `\modul` with its replacement text and we get

```
\tmpb=\tmpc=\thepage \divide\tmpc by 4 \multiply \tmpc by 4 \multiply \tmpc by -1 \advance \tmpc by \thepage\relax \the\tmpc
```

Can you see the problem? The `<number>` is there, but it's `\tmpc`. So TeX assigns the current value of `\tmpc` to `\tmpb` and moves on. Now it finds `=\thepage` and it typesets them, as it's not doing an assignment any more. Only after this it performs the following assignments.

You probably want to look at [Is a page modulo 4?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/136649/is-a-page-modulo-4) in order to solve your problem.

Unrelated, but important: never do `\newcount` in the replacement text of a macro (unless it's a macro specifically designed to allocate a new counter, but to be used just once) or a new counter register will be wasted at each call of the macro.

Comment: It's difficult to understand for me. I'm newbe in TeX. Thank you for a link.

Comment: @TarwirdurTuron The main thing is that TeX doesn't feed the result of the computation with `\modul{\thepage}{4}` to `\tmpb`, because `\modul` doesn't simply expand to a number, but it is the set of instructions for producing one.

Comment: And how to expand it to number?

Comment: might not there also be a problem with the `%` immediately after the `1` and `4` in the code?

Comment: @barbarabeeton Not in this case, although the `4` will trigger the expansion of `\loop` that starts with `\def`, so the assignment is performed correctly. But yes, it's better not having `%` after constants

Comment: @TarwirdurTuron The answer to the linked question should be what you need. Please tell if you're not able to adapt it to your needs.