# Row Numbering for every n-th multiple

Tags: numbering

I'm working in a tabular environment. I am a writing a set of 20+ rows in the environment. At first, I was going to number each row (automatically). But then it occurred to me that I could just number every fifth row: 5, 10, 15, 20... and so forth.

What is the simplest way to do this?

Here is my source code:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{array}
\newcounter{rowcount}
\setcounter{rowcount}{0}


\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{fontspec}


\setmainlanguage[variant=us]{english}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage[variant=ancient]{greek}

\newfontfamily\greekfont[Script=Greek, Scale=MatchUppercase, Ligatures=TeX]{SBL BibLit}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew,Contextuals=Alternate,Ligatures=Required]{SBL BibLit}

\begin{document}

\section*{Fragment I.1: Psalm 17:26b-(LXX)}

\begin{greek}
\begin{tabular}{@{\stepcounter{rowcount}\therowcount\hspace*{\tabcolsep}}ccccccr}

  & ουεμ                                & καί μ(ετ)α                        & πρὸς                            & καὶ μ(ετ)α    & καὶ μ(ετ)α\\
  & γαβρ                                & ἀ\d{ν}δρ\d{ὸ}\d{ς}           & ἀνδρ\d{ὸ}\d{ς}             & ἀνδρὸς        & ἀνδρὸς\\
  & θαμιμ                               & τ(\d{ε}\d{λ})ε\d{ι}ο\d{υ}  & ἀκ\d{έ}ραιον                 & ἀθώιου        & ἀμωμου\\
  & θεμα\d{μ}\d{μ}\d{α}\d{μ}  & τ(ελ)(\d{ε}\d{ι})ωθήσ\d{ι} & ἀκέραια \d{π}ρ\d{ά}ζεις  & ἀθώος ἔσηι  &  ἄμωμος (ἔσ)ηι\\
  & ουεμ                                & καὶ μ(ετ)α                        & πρὸς                            & καὶ μ(ετ)α    & μ(ετ)α & 27\\ %how do I make this last column bold? Current commands (textbf and bfseries) do not seem to work...
  & ναβαρ

\end{tabular}
\end{greek}

\end{document}
```

At the end of the day, I could always just manually input on a separate column \therowcount. I guess I'm just being curious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nice question! Unfortunately my editor is struggling with the Greek characters, so I hope you do not mind me using ASCII characters in the example. Of course, the code does work in your use case, too. You can use `\numexpr` to define a `mod` function by exploiting that it rounds fractions.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{array}
\newcounter{rowcount}
\setcounter{rowcount}{0}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{@{\stepcounter{rowcount}%
\ifnum\the\numexpr\value{rowcount}-5*(\value{rowcount}/5)=0\relax
\number\value{rowcount}%
\fi
\hspace*{\tabcolsep}
}lc}
 & A \\
 & B \\
 & C \\
 & D \\
 & E \\
 & F \\
 & G \\
 & H \\
 & I \\
 & J \\
 & K \\
 & L \\
 & M \\
 & N \\
 & O \\
 & P \\
 & Q \\
 & R \\
 & S \\
 & T \\
 & U \\
 & V \\
 & W \\
 & X \\
 & Y \\
 & Z \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

One can of course use a macro and condense it but I wanted to keep the trick explicit. It is also obvious (I hope;-) how to generalize this to other integers, i.e. not 5. You can define this to be a new column type.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{array}
\newcounter{rowcount}
\setcounter{rowcount}{0}
\newcolumntype{N}[1]{@{\stepcounter{rowcount}%
\ifnum\the\numexpr\value{rowcount}-#1*(\value{rowcount}/#1)=0\relax
\number\value{rowcount}%
\fi
\hspace*{\tabcolsep}
}l}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{N{4}c}
 & A \\
 & B \\
 & C \\
 & D \\
 & E \\
 & F \\
 & G \\
 & H \\
 & I \\
 & J \\
 & K \\
 & L \\
 & M \\
 & N \\
 & O \\
 & P \\
 & Q \\
 & R \\
 & S \\
 & T \\
 & U \\
 & V \\
 & W \\
 & X \\
 & Y \\
 & Z \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! This does the trick. I suppose the % signs are important. When I first input the code I ignored the percent signs and the output was off. Thank you for making the trick explicit, as I'm still pretty fresh to this world of LaTeX and I want to learn it well.

Comment: @Rob28 Yes, they are. They suppress spurious spaces, which can distort the output or have even more severe side-effects.

Comment: Can you use `for` loop? If I would have to write the answer (thinking on most programming languages) I would use `for` for sure, where the stop is the the number of rows, lol. Is that possible? Thank you!

Comment: @manooooh Sure, you can. The point is that this works without any packages, just using `\numexpr`. So this answer is simple, fast, easy to modify and understand, and does not suffer from incompatibilities or other threats.

Comment: @Schrödinger's cat Can you explain the order of operations here: numexpr\value{rowcount}-5*(\value{rowcount}/5)=0? I think I understand the \ifnum syntax. Just not how we're getting to 0.

Comment: @Rob28 Sure. If `rowcount` is divisible by 5, `\ifnum\the\numexpr\value{rowcount}-5*(\value{rowcount}/5)` yields 0. What happens if `rowcount` is not divisible by 5? We need to know that `\the\numexpr` rounds the result. So `5*(\value{rowcount}/5)` yields `0,0,5,5,5` for `rowcount=1,2,3,4,5`, and thus the whole term yields 0 only if `rowcount` is divisible by 5.

Comment: @Schrödinger's cat Am I to read **\the\numexpr\value{rowcount}-5*(\value{rowcount}/5)** as in value of rowcount _minus_ 5 and then _multiplied by_ (*) the value of the rowcount divided by 5?

Comment: @Rob28 Yes, this is correct. In a more mundane language this is `x-5*round(x/5)` where `x=rowcount`. See  [this comment by ShreevatsaR](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34424/how-do-i-calculate-n-modulo-3-in-latex#comment993828_34449) for some more of these tricks.

Comment: @ Schrödinger's cat Ok, these are my last 2 questions: (1) the asterisk after 5 (as in 5*) indicates rounding or multiplication? (2) I'm assuming the value of "x" does not change when it's divided by 5, right? So, say x = 7 ----> "7-5*(7/5)"

Comment: The star `*` is just a multiplication sign. And `7` gets mapped to `7-5*round(7/5)=7-5*1=2`. You can play with `\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{rowcount}
\begin{document}
\loop
\stepcounter{rowcount}%
\number\value{rowcount}:\the\numexpr\value{rowcount}-5*(\value{rowcount}/5)\relax
:\the\numexpr5*(\value{rowcount}/5)\relax\par
\ifnum\value{rowcount}<30
\repeat
\end{document}` or similar codes to see things more explicitly.

Comment: @Schrödinger's cat Thank you! I appreciate the courtesy of answering all these questions.

Answer (score 2):

Your idea is good. I defined a `\countrows` command that has as optional argument the interval of the numbering. Omitting it will number all lines.

I decided to set the numbers in the margin, with smaller type size, but this can be modified by changing the definition.

```latex
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{array}

\setmainfont{Libertinus Serif}
\setmainlanguage[variant=us]{english}
\setotherlanguage[variant=ancient]{greek}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\int_new:N \g_robxxviii_rowcount_int

\NewDocumentCommand{\countrows}{O{1}}
 {
  \int_gincr:N \g_robxxviii_rowcount_int
  \int_compare:nT { \int_mod:nn { \g_robxxviii_rowcount_int } { #1 } = 0 }
   {
    \makebox[0pt][r]
     {
      \footnotesize
      \int_to_arabic:n { \g_robxxviii_rowcount_int }\hspace{\tabcolsep}
     }
   }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\resetcountrows}{}
 {
  \int_gzero:N \g_robxxviii_rowcount_int
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\section*{Fragment I.1: Psalm 17:26b-(LXX)}

\begin{greek}
\noindent\resetcountrows
\begin{tabular}{
  @{\countrows[5]}
  ccccc
  >{\bfseries}r
  @{}
}
ουεμ     & καί μ(ετ)α     & πρὸς            & καὶ μ(ετ)α & καὶ μ(ετ)α\\
γαβρ     & ἀν̣δρὸ̣ς̣         & ἀνδρὸ̣ς̣          & ἀνδρὸς     & ἀνδρὸς\\
θαμιμ    & τ(ε̣λ̣)ει̣ου̣      & ἀκέ̣ραιον        & ἀθώιου     & ἀμωμου\\
θεμαμ̣μ̣α̣μ̣ & τ(ελ)(ε̣ι̣)ωθήσι̣ & ἀκέραια π̣ρά̣ζεις & ἀθώος ἔσηι &  ἄμωμος (ἔσ)ηι\\
ουεμ     & καὶ μ(ετ)α     & πρὸς            & καὶ μ(ετ)α & μ(ετ)α & 27\\ 
ναβαρ \\
ουεμ     & καί μ(ετ)α     & πρὸς            & καὶ μ(ετ)α & καὶ μ(ετ)α\\
γαβρ     & ἀν̣δρὸ̣ς̣         & ἀνδρὸ̣ς̣          & ἀνδρὸς     & ἀνδρὸς\\
θαμιμ    & τ(ε̣λ̣)ει̣ου̣      & ἀκέ̣ραιον        & ἀθώιου     & ἀμωμου\\
θεμαμ̣μ̣α̣μ̣ & τ(ελ)(ε̣ι̣)ωθήσι̣ & ἀκέραια π̣ρά̣ζεις & ἀθώος ἔσηι &  ἄμωμος (ἔσ)ηι\\
ουεμ     & καὶ μ(ετ)α     & πρὸς            & καὶ μ(ετ)α & μ(ετ)α & 27\\ 
ναβαρ \\
ουεμ     & καί μ(ετ)α     & πρὸς            & καὶ μ(ετ)α & καὶ μ(ετ)α\\
γαβρ     & ἀν̣δρὸ̣ς̣         & ἀνδρὸ̣ς̣          & ἀνδρὸς     & ἀνδρὸς\\
θαμιμ    & τ(ε̣λ̣)ει̣ου̣      & ἀκέ̣ραιον        & ἀθώιου     & ἀμωμου\\
θεμαμ̣μ̣α̣μ̣ & τ(ελ)(ε̣ι̣)ωθήσι̣ & ἀκέραια π̣ρά̣ζεις & ἀθώος ἔσηι &  ἄμωμος (ἔσ)ηι\\
ουεμ     & καὶ μ(ετ)α     & πρὸς            & καὶ μ(ετ)α & μ(ετ)α & 27\\ 
ναβαρ \\
ουεμ     & καί μ(ετ)α     & πρὸς            & καὶ μ(ετ)α & καὶ μ(ετ)α\\
γαβρ     & ἀν̣δρὸ̣ς̣         & ἀνδρὸ̣ς̣          & ἀνδρὸς     & ἀνδρὸς\\
θαμιμ    & τ(ε̣λ̣)ει̣ου̣      & ἀκέ̣ραιον        & ἀθώιου     & ἀμωμου\\
θεμαμ̣μ̣α̣μ̣ & τ(ελ)(ε̣ι̣)ωθήσι̣ & ἀκέραια π̣ρά̣ζεις & ἀθώος ἔσηι &  ἄμωμος (ἔσ)ηι\\
ουεμ     & καὶ μ(ετ)α     & πρὸς            & καὶ μ(ετ)α & μ(ετ)α & 27\\ 
ναβαρ \\
\end{tabular}
\end{greek}

\end{document}
```

[image]